# Ionic3 how to use tabs with other components

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic's official website, tabs just use for root element.
But I want to put some components with `<ion-tabs>` in the same level, such as:

```
<my-component></my-component>
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab ...></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ...></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ...></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

[image]

Because each tab has its own stack, I don't want to use other component instead of it.
How I can do this?

Comment: Because each tab has it's own stack,I don't want to use other component instead of it. Can I do it or how to do it?

Comment: maybe segments are suited for your use case?